# The difference in results when the dynamic planning algorithm problem C++ and Python are implemented?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

In Jedi Survivor, there are three levels of armor and body armor, each recorded as 1,2,3. Each time you can only pick up what you don't have, or upgrade a low level of equipment to a high level, ask how many upgrade routes are there from nothing to "Armor Level 3 Body Armor Level 3 Body Armor"? The current state is represented by an ordered number of pairs (body armor, armor), both of which have values 0-3, e.g. (0,0)->(0,1)->(0,3)->(3,3) as an upgrade strategy.

**The theory is that it's a 4*4 array, I wonder why python 4*4 array can be implemented, but c++ must be written as int[4][4] i.e. 5*5 array result to be right, int[3][3] is calculated wrong? (The result is the last element, which is 106)**

python:

```
dp = [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        for m in range(j):
            dp[i][j] += dp[i][m]
        for m in range(i):
            dp[i][j] += dp[m][j]
dp
```

output:106  (right answer)
c++:

```
#include<iostream>
int dp[3][3];
int main (){
    dp[0][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++){
            for (int m = 0; m < i; m++)
                dp[i][j] += dp[m][j];
            for (int m = 0; m < j; m++)
                dp[i][j] += dp[i][m];
       }
    }
  std::cout<<dp[3][3]<<std::endl;
}
```

**output: 1495(worng! but i don't know why?  why output in c++ is wrong?)**

Comment: Quick answer -- C++ and Python are two different languages.  That's like asking why French has 3 accent marks, but Spanish has one.

Comment: Your C++ code has undefined behavior because `result` is supposed to return an int but it never does. It's clear that the two innermost loops are different in the two programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it. Your problem is that you use an array of size 3x3 as if it was of size 4x4.
A working version:

```
#include<iostream>

int dp[4][4];
int main ()
{
    dp[0][0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            for (int m = 0; m < j; m++)
                dp[i][j] += dp[i][m];
            for (int m = 0; m < i; m++)
                dp[i][j] += dp[m][j];
       }
    }
    std::cout<<dp[3][3]<<std::endl; 
}
```

The important change was `int dp[3][3];` to `int dp[4][4];`. With that, your code above works.
Without that, you accessed your array out of bounds, which is undefined behaviour. The 1495 was just a result of how the compiler interpreted your code, but as it is UB, any result would have been valid. That's the deceptive thing of UB - it can often look like it does something reasonable, making it appear like it was a mistake in your algorithm, when it isn't.
I did some further minor changes while experimenting. One was to switch the two inner for loops, but that one is not necessary. I also changed `<= 3` to `< 4` as that is a more usual style, but obviously also not required.

For the future, get acquainted with using a debugger, or print out your result in between the steps. If you have working phyton code, you could do the same there, and then compare the behaviour of both programs. Note however that in your case, the result would probably have looked strange - I did this while experimenting, and the result is funny, see http://www.cpp.sh/8aufco . The variable i runs to 257 despite the loop constraining it to 3. I have no idea why this happens like that - just the result of UB.

You might want to consider changing the raw array to `std::vector` or `std::array`, but I left this at it is for now.
Your main should `return 0;` as a good practice, although it works as it is.
You should not use any global variables in C++, like you do with `dp`. Simply declare it inside your main (or wherever you later use it). Global variables are an easy source for errors (note that constants are fine).

Comment: Thank you so much, I found out that I made a stupid mistake. Thank you for these specifications and suggestions, thank you again

Comment: @zhuowei Don't call it a stupid mistake. Looks more like something you simply overlooked. Happens to me all the time. Stuff like that is hard to debug, and I kind of spotted it by chance.